# How to bind dired-up-directory to key

Tags: key-bindings, dired

I'm tryng to bind F6 to dired-up-directory using

`(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>")`

but when I use this in dired-mode, I get

`<f6>` is undefined.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the command that you want to bind to that key, as the second argument to `global-set-key`: `(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") #'dired-up-directory)`. Your sexp isn't even closed - it's missing a right paren (as well as a second argument).

But really you don't want to bind that key *globally* to `dired-up-directory` (do you?). You want to bind it to that command only in `dired-mode`:

```lisp
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<f6>") #'dired-up-directory)
```

Comment: I get this when using this definition:-**Symbol's value as variable is void: dired-mode-map**

Comment: @balanga: For a major mode keymap to be available you need to at least load the library defining the mode, and typically you need to enable the mode. If you're in `dired-mode` then `dired-mode-map` is defined.

Comment: How do I define it just in dired-mode? Do I need to edit dired.el?

Comment: Define what just in `dired-mode`? `dired-mode-map` is, and should be, defined globally. It is used in `dired-mode`.